# How to exclude duplicate native library from Gradle project dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have two Gradle modules for Android, one is a library and one is an application, and the application has a dependency on the module, like so: `compile project(path ':library' configuration: 'debug')`

The problem is that both modules use JNI, so they both package`libc++_shared.so` 
 from the NDK, causing:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException:
Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so
```

I tried using `packagingOptions`, but it seems like I can only use that to completely exclude that file from being packaged at all, not just from being copied from the other module?

Answer (score 3):

What type of `packagingOptions` have you tried to use? Probably, `exlude`? It looks like `pickFirst` should work for you. In this case you explicitly tell Gradle that you know about the problem and accept any of these files. Depending on the architectures you support you may need only some of the lines. You can find details [in documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html)

```
android {

 // some stuff
 packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libgnustl_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so'
    }
}
```